# CouchDB Flatten Data in a View

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

**What am I trying to achieve?** 
I am trying to create a CouchDB view that builds up aggregate data from my workouts document (specifically based on a custom date range), by returning a completed result from my database, having to do no additional processing outside my view.

**What my view looks like:**

```js
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.memberMainGym, doc.startTime, doc.userProfileId, 'totalWorkouts'], 1);
}
```

**What my query looks like:** 
?start_key=["Centurion","2023-01-01"]&end_key=["Centurion","2023-11-01",{}]&group_level=3

**Problem:** 
I need a total number of workouts done per user in this example, but the date in the second key is preventing the data from being flattened:

```json
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-25T16:00:00.000Z","JU3CnlIrUkNtoKEYlKFgFpBhQc72"],"value":1},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T04:00:00.000Z","JU3CnlIrUkNtoKEYlKFgFpBhQc72"],"value":1},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T04:30:00.000Z","JU3CnlIrUkNtoKEYlKFgFpBhQc72"],"value":2},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T07:00:00.000Z","ZqQp8364k5WCns41DYGRoRRuCoz1"],"value":1},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T10:00:00.000Z","x8nb12YpAnTfRVIvluC9FkGpShK2"],"value":1},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T10:00:00.000Z","ZqQp8364k5WCns41DYGRoRRuCoz1"],"value":1},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T15:00:00.000Z","lkFRhOzQlph9jU350fsbqfIUU7S2"],"value":3},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T15:00:00.000Z","MHjnfBgUW1ZViFTB0X911AewbyZ2"],"value":1},
{"key":["Centurion","2018-06-26T15:30:00.000Z","ZqQp8364k5WCns41DYGRoRRuCoz1"],"value":1},
```

**My question:**
Given the above information, my problem seems to be that the date in the 2nd key is preventing me from flattening this data, which causes me to have to map over the result in my server and flattening it myself.
Is there any way I can flatten the dates in the view? Giving me only the total number of workouts done per user.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried swopping the startTime and userProfileId keys around, but then I have to specify a userProfileId in order to pass in a custom date.

?start_key=["Centurion","","2023-01-01"]&end_key=["Centurion","","2023-11-01",{}]&group_level=3

```js
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.memberMainGym, doc.userProfileId, doc.startTime, 'totalWorkouts'], 1);
}
```

Comment: The result you give in the "problem" section does not correspond to  the view definition you give. The length of the `key` array is different.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the results you would expect?

Comment: What is your reduce function? `_sum` I presume? Did you try writing your own?